# What does findviewbyid means in android studio

Tags: java, android

What does findviewbyid means in android studio

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-work-of-findViewById-in-Android-studio

Comment: please search online before asking, and ask only if you did not find an answer. this link was the first google result for "findviewbyid android studio"

Comment: see the [android documaentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)).

Comment: You can find many books and also online tutorials for learning android app programming. You may want to follow one of these to learn the basics of android programming before trying to understand random lines of code in existing code.

Comment: Very useful question. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View is a class where all the widgets are defined.

R.id.myName specifies a view whose ID name is called myName

R is a Class that contains the ID's of all the Views

findViewById is the method that finds the View by the ID it is given. So findViewById(R.id.myName) finds the View with name 'myName'. Hope this helps :)

Comment: So is it like where you have a id called my button and you call the Id name

Comment: Yes, it is basically just getting the View with that specific ID. The Android docs on View is also really helpful if you need to get some more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

Comment: Very helpful answer and explanation